# adding environment variable to ida pro

Tags: ida

I am trying to debug a linux application using remote debugging feature in ida pro. I use the remote linux debugger on windows after running the ida server on linux. My problem is that the file run normally in the linux environment since environment variables are accessible to the file. However, on using ida in windows the environment variables seems to be inaccessible and give error that I should define environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Run the linux program normally, then attach to the running process from IDA. Of course this won't work if you have to debug the application startup.

2) Define (and export) the environment variables on Linux before you start `linux_server`. When you attach IDA to the running server, and start your program, the environment variables should get passed through to your program.

Of course, defining any environment variables in windows won't alter the environent of your linux program.

Comment: Thank you I figured out that for some reason when running linux server as sudo it will not work as the environment variables were defined for normal user. On running normally with sudo, it works.